# Different date saved to database - wrong time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, datetime, activerecord

When I fetch a date from FullCalendar with Javascript I have the following values:

```
Fri Sep 13 2013 08:30:33 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

After I save that date to database I see that in database there are different values:

```
2013-09-13 12:00:00.000000
```

So, date is automatically converted to UTC and saved like that into database. How to save the correct date into database? I don't want to hardcode it :)

Thank you.

Comment: What is the column datatype in the database? It doesn't quite look like a time zone issue as the difference doesn't add up to 4 hours.

Comment: Column datatype is datetime.

Answer (score 3):

For that you need to define your time zone in your application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'YOUR-TIME-ZONE'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes = false
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, the rails app timezone is UTC. Whenever the record is saved the date, datetime, time fields are saved with DB's timezone but when they are fetched back in models it is converted back to UTC.

So, in your case set your application timezone in application.rb like this

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

Now, whenever the records are fetched from database it will always be converted to CST timezone irrespective of DBs timezone.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you. I will check how it works when I fetch dates back to calendar.