# Wrong date saved to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord, fullcalendar

I'm trying to save a date to database but I can't get it right. The date is constantly 4 hours after the real date. I'm using FullCalendar to display events.

I save the date like this:

```
var dateEnd = new Date();
            dateEnd.setDate(day);
            dateEnd.setMonth(month);
            dateEnd.setFullYear(year);
            dateEnd.setHours(hour);
            dateEnd.setMinutes(minutes);

            alert('Next slot: ' + dateEnd);


            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', { title: 'YOUR TITLE', start: date, end: dateEnd,allDay: false, backgroundColor: '#378006' }, true );

            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/create",
              data: {
                start_date: date,
                end_date: dateEnd,
                doctor_id: '1',
                user_id: '1'
              }
            });
```

I display events like this:

```
events: 
        [
        <% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
        {
          //alert(<%= appointment.start_date %>);
          title  : "Reserved",
          start  : "<%= appointment.start_date.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
          end    : "<%= appointment.end_date.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
          allDay : false
        },
        <% end %>
        ],
```

I put this inside application.rb like in this thread [Different date saved to database - wrong time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778985/different-date-saved-to-database-wrong-time-zone) but it's still the same:

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
    config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes = false
```

The date in database is always 4 hours ahead and when I fetch dates back from database they are displayed incorrectly on FullCalendar.

Comment: Sounds like a timezone problem. What timezone does your database think it is? What does your code think it is?

Comment: My database saves everything in UTC timezone. I am currently in New York and if I create an event at 10am it will be saved to database like it's 2pm. So, 4 hours difference.

Comment: I think I found the solution. It seems it doesn't want to convert automatically so after the date I need to put 'in_time_zone' and then it will convert it normally to assigned timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data manipulations should occur in your controller, not in your view. The view should only spit out the pre-processed values.

I'd recommend mapping your `@appointments` to their `:start` and `:end` string equivalents as an array of hashes or array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really want `config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes = false`.  That's telling rails that you do not want times to be represented in `'Central Time (US & Canada)'`, but instead that you want them in UTC.

Comment: I removed that line but it's still the same. Database adds additional 4 hours.

Comment: I think I found the solution. It seems it doesn't want to convert automatically so after the date I need to put 'in_time_zone' and then it will convert it normally to assigned timezone.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for now:

application.rb:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

When I display events I add 'in_time_zone' for each date:

```
        events: 
        [
        <% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
        {
          title  : "Reserved",
          start  : "<%= appointment.start_date.in_time_zone.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
          end    : "<%= appointment.end_date.in_time_zone.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
          allDay : false
        },
        <% end %>
        ]
```

This automatically converts date from database which is in UTC format to assigned time zone.

Comment: Your data manipulations should occur in your controller, not in your view. The view should only spit out the pre-processed values.

Comment: I know but I have problems to make it work in my controller. What do you suggest to do in controller? Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend mapping your `@appointments` to their `:start` and `:end` string equivalents as an array of hashes or array of arrays.

Comment: @theTinMan - If you want, you can post your solution and I can mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: Dealing with time zones in web apps is frustrating, especially when you can have people hitting it from all over the world.